# Error when starting docker service on Windows 10

Tags: docker

I had some problems in Hyper-V on Windows 10. Everything seems to be resolved now, however when I try to start the docker service I get the following error:

> Service cannot be started. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load
>   type 'Docker.Backend.ITimeIntegrationService' from assembly
>   'Docker.Backend, Version=1.12.5.9503, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   at Docker.Service.DockerService.DoRun()
>   at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)

As per other blogs that I've found, I have uninstalled docker, removed everything from c:\programdata\docker and restarted the PC a number of times. When I reinstall I still get the same error.

Any ideas on how to repair this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this on the [docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-uninstall-docker-for-windows/15661/11):

```
'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\MobyLinux.ps1' -Destroy
$service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='com.docker.service'"
$service.StopService()
$service.Delete()
Start-Sleep -s 5
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "~/AppData/Local/Docker"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "~/AppData/Roaming/Docker"
takeown.exe /F "C:\ProgramData\Docker" /R /A /D Y
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Docker" /T /C /grant Administrators:F
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\ProgramData\Docker"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Program Files\Docker"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Docker"
Remove-Item -Force "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Docker for Windows.lnk"
Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $.PSPath} | Where-Object { $.DisplayName -eq "Docker" } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Get-ChildItem hklm:\software\classes\installer\products | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Where-Object { $_.ProductName -eq "Docker" } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Get-Item 'HKLM:\software\Docker Inc.' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Get-ItemProperty -path HKCU:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\Run -name "Docker for Windows" | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

So I did an uninstall using the docker installer, ran the above powershell script, did another restart and reinstalled docker and everything seems to be working.